# Is there single column Wallace tree?

Tags: adder, design-rules

I googled and learn the rules about [Wallace tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_tree).

If I understand right, wallace tree is designed to multiply. However, I want to know Is there **single column** wallace tree in the initial layer just to add n bits? I have lost in google and can't find it.

Comment: What would be the point? Wouldn't that just be an adder?

Comment: @Hearth Yes, just adder

Comment: So... what differentiates your "single column wallace tree" from a regular old adder? Why would it be called a wallace tree?